# Get string from DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have XML file which contains my data and I want from dropdownlist save choose string to this xml.
In my view I have this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>MatchXML</legend>
    ...
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Team)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Team", (SelectList)ViewBag.Team, String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Team)
    </div>
    ...

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

In controller:

```
    public ActionResult Pridat()
    {
        ViewBag.Team = new SelectList(repo.GetTeams(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Pridat(MatchXML match, string Team)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                ViewBag.Team = new SelectList(repo.GetTeams(), "Name", "Name");
                match.Team = repo.GetTeamByName(Team);
                repo.AddMatch(match);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //error msg for failed insert in XML file
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error creating record. " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        return View(match);
    }
```

Models looks:

```
public class MatchXML
{
    public int MatchXMLID { get; set; }
    public string Opponent { get; set; }
    public DateTime MatchDate { get; set; }
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public int Round { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual User Coach { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying do some modification to do this but it is not working. I can do it with TeamID and saving ID but I want in xml save string (name of team). Thanks for help

Edit:
I updated show code of controller and view method.

Comment: what is the question here ? what is not working? your dropdown is not rendered correctly? or you dont know how to get text value from it ? if so, you just put string argument named Team to your action.

Comment: DropDown is rendering correctly but I really don´t know how to get value from it. I tried it with string argument but It is not working. I get error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Team'.

Comment: Do you have a form and a post action? Its not clear what you are trying to do and what is not working.

Comment: I updated sample of my code, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the dropdown to the `Team` complex property (first argument of the DropDownList helper). This doesn't make sense. You can bind only to scalar values. I would also recommend you using the strongly typed version of the helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Team.TeamID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Team, String.Empty)
```

This way you will populate the `TeamID` property in the POST action with the selected value from the dropdown.

Also replace:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Team)
```

with:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Team.TeamID)
```

Comment: When I try this, I have this error when posting: The ViewData item that has the key 'Team.TeamID' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'. DDL is popolutated but cant post.